Proof of correctness for a greedy algorithm finding the lexicographically smallest array
The following problem is from Codeforces.
We are given an array $a$, containing $n$ integers. In a single operation, we can take some index $i$, with $1\le i\le n$, increase $a_i$ by one, and move it to the back of the array. For example, Taking $a=[5, 2, 4, 3, 1]$ and choosing $i=3$, we increment $a_3=4$ and move it to the back of the array, obtaining $[5, 2, 3, 1, 5]$.
We are tasked with finding the lexicographically smallest array one can get by using a finite number of these operations.

I came up with the following algorithm for this problem:
Identify all indices $i$ such that there exists some index $j$ with $i<j\le n$ with $a_i>a_j$. If there are no such indices, terminate. Otherwise, choose the index $i$ with the smallest value of $a_i$ and perform an operation on it. We repeat this until we eventually terminate.
The insight behind the algorithm is that these problematic indices $i$ must evenutally be operated on to reach a non-decreasing array. The order in which we operate on them is also important, as choosing the smallest value of $a_i$ makes less problematic indices in the future, so we avoid redundancy.
Continuing our example, taking $a=[5, 2, 4, 3, 1]$, the algorithm produces
$$[5, 4, 3, 1, 3]$$
$$[5, 4, 1, 3, 4]$$
$$[5, 1, 3, 4, 5]$$
$$[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]$$
and as at this point there are no more problematic indices, we terminate.
What I wish to prove is that the algorithm terminates and outputs the correct array.
Another thing that I noticed is that the lexicographically smallest array that one can obtain by repeatedly using this operation seems to be a non-decreasing array obtained in the least number of operations. I'm not sure how to prove this either.
All insight and effort are appreciated!

Edit: Some new remarks are the following.
After the $k$th performed operation (starting at $k=1$), $[a_{n-k+1}, a_{n-k+2}, ..., a_n]$ is non-decreasing. This proves that the algorithm terminates and gives an upper bound to the number of steps $k\le n$ (in fact, $k\le n - 1$, which is the best possible upper bound).
Another observation is that no new problematic indices appear in iteration $k\ge 2$. This is because new problematic indices appear when some nonproblematic index $j$ has $a_j > a_i$, where $a_i$ was just incremented and moved to the end of the array. If this didn't occur in iteration $k=1$, it won't occur later, as all subsequent values are $\ge a_i$ by construction.
The proof is pretty much done after noticing that operating on nonproblematic indices is suboptimal and that operating on indices with value greater than the smallest value out of problematic indices forces some index to be operated on twice in the future, which is suboptimal as well (since removing one of those two operations yields the exact same array, just with one element smaller by one).
Also, I've found a counterexample to the claim that the lexicographically smallest array that one can obtain by repeatedly using this operation is a non-decreasing array obtained in the least number of operations. This doesn't always hold, as the trivial example of $[2, 2, 1]$ illustrates :P

Did it get accepted?

It did get accepted :)
